# If matrix $A$ is invertible, prove that $A^{m}$ is also invertible for $m>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have this exercise:

> If matrix $A$ is invertible, prove that $A^{m}$ is also invertible for $m>0 \quad \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ furthermore $(A^{m})^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{m}.$

My proposed solution is the following:

For induction.

If $A^{m}$ for $m=1$ is invertible, then for $m=1$ is true.

Suppose that for $m\geq 1, \quad A^{m}$,  is invertible.

Inductive Step:
$$\text{If } A^{(m+1)} \text{ is invertible}$$
$$ A^{(m+1)} = A^{m} \cdot {A} $$

By hypothesis: $A$ is invertible and $A^{m}$ is invertible by hypothesis of induction then $A^{m}\cdot A$ is invertible (the product of two invertible matrices is again an invertible matrix).

And therefore, $A^{m+1}$ is invertible. Therefore, $A^{m}$ is invertible for $m\geq1$.

It only remains to prove that $(A^{m})^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{m}$

The prove is also by induction. For $m=1$ the result is immediate.

Assuming that it is satisfied for $m\geq 1$
$$ (A^{m+1})^{-1}=(A^{m}A)^{-1}=A^{-1}(A^{m})^{-1} $$
Applying the induction hypothesis
$$ A^{-1}(A^{m})^{-1}=A^{-1}(A^{-1})^{m}=(A^{-1})^{m+1} \Box $$

Is my solution correct or Am I breaking the mathematics?

Comment: It's correct. You don't need the first part of your proof if you prove $(A^m)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^m$.

Comment: this proof is fine. nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are right.

You can also prove it in many other way like using concept of linear Transformation & determinant.

We know, A matrix is invertible iff $\det A\neq0.$
Now, $\det (A^m) = (\det A)^m.$

if $\det A\neq0,$ $(\det A)^m \neq0.$

So $A^m$ is invertible.

Comment: also requires an inductive argument

Answer (score 0):

> By hypothesis: $A$ is invertible and $A^m$ is invertible by hypothesis of
> induction then $A^m⋅A$ is invertible (the product of two invertible
> matrices is again an invertible matrix).

This is a contradiction. If you can use that the product of invertible matrix is invertible, the problem is trivial: $A^m=A\cdot A\cdot ...\cdot A$.

You can continue as follows:

By hypothesis $A$ and $A^m$ are invertible. Then exist $B$ and $C$ such that $AB=Id$ and $A^mC=Id$.

Finally, $A^{m+1}\cdot B\cdot C=A^m\cdot A\cdot B \cdot C =A^m\cdot (A\cdot B) \cdot C =A^m\cdot Id \cdot C = A^m \cdot C = Id$.

Comment: The problem is trivial, but an induction argument is needed to prove it formally. Your $\dots$ are an implicit induction.

Comment: No. What I suggested is a way to end the induction. What I'm saying is that if you can use that premise the proof is trivial and does not require induction.

Comment: It does require induction. To go from "the product of two invertible matrices is invertible" to "the product of $m$ invertible matrices is invertible for all $m \geq 1$" requires an induction argument.

Comment: It’s certainly not a contradiction. Do you know what a contradiction is? Your argument is that this is circular reasoning. It isn’t really, but circular reasoning is not a contradiction, just an error.

Comment: Yes that is a contradiction. You are assuming that the case $ m = 2 $ is previously true.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo what exactly is the contradiction? what goes wrong